# Why does one of two identical VS2015 projects produce error C4995?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, deprecated

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community under Windows 10.

I have this code in file "xie.cpp":

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"

void s()
{
     XInputEnable(TRUE);
}
```

Here's stdafx.h:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>
#include <Xinput.h>
```

When I compile xie.cpp, I get this error message:

`xie.cpp(5): error C4995: 'XInputEnable': name was marked as #pragma deprecated`

As I found this rather puzzling, I duplicated the project tree, appending a "2" to the name of the vcxproj files, and added the duplicate to the solution. When I compile xie.cpp in the duplicated project, I don't get the error message.

I've checked all the project configuration settings for the two projects. They are idendtical. I deleted the x64 subtree where the compiled object files are recompiled. No matter what I do, the original project compiles with the error, while the copied project compiles successfully. I suppose I could just go on with the copied project, but I sure would like to know why I am getting that error message.

Can anyone suggest a further line of investigation for me?

**UPDATE**

Problem was that I don't understand precompiled headers as well as I would like to. When I change the Target Platform Version from 8.1 to 10.0.14393.0, and then rebuild the project, the Xinput.h header comes from the Windows 10 kit, not the Window 8.1 kit. The only difference is that the Windows 10 version includes these lines:

```cpp
#if(_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN10)
#pragma deprecated(XInputEnable)
#endif
```

Both _WIN32_WINNT and _WIN32_WINNT_WIN10 have the value 0x0A00 so, indeed, XInputEnable is marked deprecated in this version of Xinput.h

Anyone know why?

Comment: Right-click the function name in the project that produces the warning and select "Go To Definition".  You'll see the deprecation just below the function declaration.  Microsoft wants you to stop using that function.  Whether you see the warning depends on the SDK you target and what version of Windows you target with the _WIN32_WINNT macro.  It isn't otherwise clear exactly why they want you to do this, the MSDN article has no details about it.

Comment: Thanks @Hans, that would have gotten me there sooner than my own fiddling did. In fact, VS finds both platform's versions, making it quite apparent that the W10 file marks it deprecated, while the W8.1 file did not. I am guessing you just no longer need to call it before using the other XInput functions. I'll test that and post here.

Comment: Yup, when I compile and link for the 10.0.14393.0 platform and just leave the call to XInputEnable out, the other XInput functions I'm using still work. A word about that in the online documentation would have been nice.

Comment: *Anyone know why?* Because 0x0A00 >= 0x0A00, so `(_WIN32_WINNT >= WIN32_WINNT_WIN10)` is true? :-)

Comment: Why is XInputEnable deprecated? (But you knew that's what I asked, of course ;).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that VS2015 does not regard a change in target platform in a project's configuration as a reason to recompile the headers. As a result, even though a platform change can swap one set of headers for another, after a platform change you will still be using the previously precompiled headers until you force them to be recompiled explicitly.

The effect here was to mask the fact that my working program actually wasn't identical to the one with the bug, as the working program was still using the old headers (where XInputEnable is not marked as deprecated), notwithstanding that my configurations and the source files I wrote myself were all identical across the two projects.

I guess the lesson is that, if you change target platform, you should do a rebuild immediately.